# Firebase Web Authentication - what about server side?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-authentication

I'd like to authenticate users using Firebase and Firebase UI. I have just started out with it.
I was thinking to use it as all tutorials suggest, and that is checking for a valid user in the promise, providing the developers a way to get that user's email, uid and the provider (maybe a picture too).

But then I thought, what about my server side? couldn't someone just copy the previously logged in user's email, and by using devtools just populate the fields as they see fit, and then just start using the web app?

Isn't there a way for my server to query Firebase under the hood so that I can be sure that user is still logged in?

Would that accessToken might be useful for that? Is there a library that helps contacting Firebase servers?

```
{"displayName”:”someone”
"email”:”some@one.com",
"emailVerified":false,
"phoneNumber":null,
"photoURL":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p100x100/535143_101537414228324dd23_7957838239360_n.jpg?,
"uid":"6yC3n39SsnOeFNZ6pJ0Yaw1vF2e3",
"accessToken”:”hjeher38738743j4k34.....", // <-- IMMEDIATE SUSPECT
"providerData":[
{
"uid":"987239872349872",
"displayName":"Some User",
"photoURL":"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p100x100/83487843_3453453453453$%_32487234.jpg",
"email":"some@mail.com",
"phoneNumber":null,
"providerId":"facebook.com"
}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase ID token are so-called bearer tokens, any party having the token is assumed to have the permissions associated with that token. Since that is rather powerful, these tokens automatically expire (after about an hour) and need to be refreshed at that point.

On a server, you can [decode the token and verify that it is valid](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library). Once you've done that, verify that the token has not expired by checking its `exp` property against the actual time.